# Wrong billing address when booking flights

Tags: air-travel, international-travel, payment-cards

When I booked a flight, I accidentally missed a line in the billing address but the address is partially complete. Will it be any problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is "no". You should be able to check-in and fly without any issue. No for the invoice, you might not receive it if the address is wrong. You can probably contact the airline to make the correction after the fact.

Comment: I heard that some verification system will check if the billing address matches my credit card information. I don't know if the payment will be denied or if any other issues will arise from the mismatch.

Comment: Yes it could get rejected but it isn't too likely to happen...

Comment: So how can I know if I am rejected?

Comment: Check out your booking on the website. Or even better, call them.

Comment: @BrianYang you can also check your credit card account to see if the ticket transaction was posted.

Comment: The airline website shows "Paid by credit card (card #)". I assume my payment was successful, isn't it?

Comment: @phoog I found in the confirmation email that Lufthansa requires presenting the credit card at the airport when check in. Just wondering if they will find out the mismatch and refuse me checking in. Will they swipe the card or just take a look at my card to verify?

Comment: @BrianYang I agree with Malvolio: the card-at-checkin requirement is to prove that the traveller is the cardholder, or is authorized by the cardholder to travel at the cardholder's expense. An address mismatch will not be a problem; the airline doesn't really care all that much about your address.

Comment: @phoog So what about some credit card address verification method like AVS which some companies use? I'm a little confused here.

Comment: @BrianYang the airline cares about your address inasmuch as they need to for billing purposes. Once they get your money, they don't care. In particular, they don't care about your address when you check in, because they already have the money at that point.

Answer (score 2):

Billing address is strictly for billing.  If they issued the ticket, you are fine.

For most vendors, the credit-card company gives them progressively lower rates as they collect more information, so if the vendor supplies your name and address, the transaction only costs them (for example) 1.8% but with the credit-card number, it's 1.9%.

Once you have the ticket, only your name (and, if they are feeling enthusiastic, your birthday) matters.

Comment: I found in the confirmation email that Lufthansa requires presenting the credit card at the airport when check in. Just wondering if they will find out the mismatch and refuse me checking in. Will they swipe the card or just take a look at my card to verify?

Comment: Typically they will only check that name and the last four numbers match the card that was used to buy the ticket.  It isn't metaphysically impossible that they could re-run the card and ask the credit-card company to check the address, but they didn't do it when you _purchased_ the ticket, why should they do it now?  For one thing, it's a lot more likely to catch someone who has changed home addresses since buying the ticket than anyone else.  And what would it get them in return?  An unhappy customer and an empty seat it's too late to fill.

Answer (score 2):

You should be fine.  Generally the credit card is at least authorized at the time that you check out, so if the system required an exact match on the billing address it would have flagged as an error at that point in time.

If you want to double check you could always check your credit card account to see if the payment has gone through.